# DynamoDB how to make a query that have compare 2 field?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Query Pattern:

Get all posts where upvotes > downvotes

Schema

```
Post = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    hashKey: true
  },
  upvote: {
    type: Number,
  },
  downvote: {
    type: Number,
  }
});
```

How to achieve this query pattern?

Comment: dynamodb is super-simple database, dont expect to have any fancy queries. Swayamraina is basically right, altough I believe the best solution is the one he mentioned just as `or store the diff to use it in more queries`. Just create one more field that has difference of upvotes and downvotes (you need to fill properly it in your code) and then create Index (Global Secondary Index) with partition key on that new field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB splits all the data according to the partition key (PK) i.e. your data is divided into multiple servers for storage. 
So to retrieve the data you need to atleast pass the partition key.

I believe your use-case is `get all posts where upvotes > downvotes`

Since this is a global query and not related to any partition or specific entry in the dynamodb table, You need to use a secondary index (sparse index via GSI).

To achieve this, you can create an additional attribute called `upvotes_gt_downvotes` and store this attribute only if upvotes are greater than downvotes (or store the diff to use it in more queries). Additionally, you will need to make this new attribute (upvotes_gt_downvotes) along with timestamp the sort-key (SK) for the GSI table.

To get the result you will have to scan this GSI. Note that this GSI will only have records which satisfy your query and will be removed from the GSI as soon as the attribute is deleted from the record. 
While downvoting, if this value becomes 0 or -ve you will have to delete this attribute when updating the record. (deleting this attribute automatically removes the record from GSI)